# Deleting a file that doesn't exist on S3 deletes the folder if that is the last file. How do we prevent this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So, I have the following structure on S3:

mainbucket

- DataFeeds/
- Statement/

We had incidents where the `DataFeeds/` folder was being deleted! So, I tested with following:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket mainbucket --key DataFeeds/.donotdelete
```

But, if I execute this (deleting `blah.txt` even if it does not exists) the `DataFeeds/` folder gets deleted too:

```
aws s3 rm s3://mainbucket/DataFeeds/blah.txt
```

So, how do we prevent a folder from being deleted on `S3`?

Versions used:
`aws-cli/2.2.46 Python/3.9.7 Darwin/20.6.0 source/x86_64 prompt/off`

Comment: I'm confused - your commands don't line up; the second command won't replace the first nor will it delete any "folders". What is your actual questions? This is not reproducible.

Comment: Apologies, copied the wrong command. Fixed it. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: All good, your question still references `blah.txt`. Can you also highlight the files in each folder in main bucket? It's important to know

Comment: There is only one file in the `DataFeeds` folder and that is `.donotdelete`. Yes it references `blah.txt` which does not exists, and that was my point precisely, as to why it was deleting the `DataFeeds` folder even when `blah.txt` does not exists! You can test it for yourself.

Comment: Sorry @ErmiyaEskandary ... fixed the question.

Comment: Unable to reproduce this with aws cli version info as: `aws-cli/1.20.65 Python/3.9.0 Darwin/19.6.0 botocore/1.21.65`.

Comment: @iyerland I could’ve answered (John worded it perfectly however), I just wanted to make the question a bit clearer for others :) no need to apologise; have a wonderful day!

Comment: Thanks @ErmiyaEskandary!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Folders do not exist in Amazon S3. It is a 'flat' storage service where the `Key` (filename) of an object includes the full path, including directories.

Amazon S3 will 'simulate' folders for you. For example, if you upload a file to `invoices/january.txt`, then the `invoices` directory will 'magically' appear. If you then delete that object, the directory will then 'disappear'. This is because it never actually existed.

If you use the **Create folder** button in the S3 management console, it will create a **zero-length object with the same name as the directory**. This will 'force' the directory to appear in the bucket listing. Deleting the zero-length object will cause the directory to disappear if there are no objects with that same Prefix (path).

The best advice for using S3 is to **pretend that folders exist**. You can place an object in any path and the (pretend) directories will magically appear. Do not worry about directories disappearing, since they never actually existed!

If you *really* need empty directories to stay around, use that **Create folder** button to create the zero-length object. It will stay around until you delete the zero-length object.

Comment: This is finally making sense now! whew!